# Is this sentence correct without any article?

Tags: articles

> I would be packing things.

Is it correct if I do not put any article before 'things': a, an, or the?

Answer (score 1):

'things' is plural, so you can't use an indefinite article.

'packing the things.' is fine if you want to emphasize that you're packing *specific* things mentioned before. However, 'packing things.' is perfectly idiomatic if there is no emphasis, or the emphasis is on the packing, not the things. In that case, you can also simply say 'packing.'

What does puzzle me is in which situation you want to use the conditional ('would be') in combination with 'packing'. I can only imagine something like this:

> - What would you do if you didn't have to work this evening?
> - I would be packing things.